# Is there any data on herbal supplements interfering with the efficacy of vaccination?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, immune-system, covid

Here's an excerpt from a [paper](https://www.dovepress.com/coronil-a-tri-herbal-formulation-attenuates-spike-protein-mediated-sar-peer-reviewed-fulltext-article-JIR#) published in *"Journal of Inflammation Research"* by Dove Press for a popular and controversial herbal supplement from India:

> Coronil effectively inhibited the interaction of ACE-2 not only with
> the wild-type S protein (SWT) but also with its currently prevalent
> and more infectious variant (SD614G) and another mutant (SW436R) with
> significantly higher affinity toward ACE-2

Now assuming what the paper says is true, the herbal drug is mediating the interaction between spike protien and host cells.

In vaccination, the spike proteins are introduced to body through various methods, so that the immune system can interact with it and familiarize itself with the spike protein before hand.

But if the herbal drug, as claimed, reduces the interaction of spike protein itself, then is it a possibility that the drug can interfere in the efficacy of vaccine?

Comment: Wow.  Excellent question.  Upvoted.  How popular is this supplement (hundreds of thousands of people taking it? millions taking it?  hundreds of millions?  over a billion?)?  Also, I'm trying to learn more about the journal "Journal of Inflammation Research".  Is it generally considered a quality and respected journal?

Comment: @RockPapaerLz-MaskitorCasket Thank you. Its extremely popular. I'm not sure about the Journal of Inflammation Research.

Comment: You're welcome.  This certainly seems like a topic very worthy of research, especially given the current COVID-19 pandemic.

Comment: I don't know anything about Coronil, but a quick search indicates it is likely an Ayurvedic substance. Following that lead, the English Wikipedia states "The theory and practice of Ayurveda is pseudoscientific.[3][4][5] The Indian Medical Association (IMA) characterises the practice of modern medicine by Ayurvedic practitioners as quackery.[6] Ayurveda is heavily practiced in India and Nepal, where around 80% of the population report using it." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayurveda). It's concerning/fascinating that 80% of populations would use something deemed as "quackery". (continued...)

Comment: (...continued) But I have no information regarding the reputation or integrity of the Indian Medical Association (IMA), and whether or not bias is present in their evaluations.

Comment: @RockPaperLz Concerning perhaps, but not too surprising. Non-evidence-based practices, especially religious ones, are quite common all around. Everyone likes easy fixes and people selling them like making money. It takes a lot of regulatory effort to suppress them, and even in places with fairly strong controls over pharmaceuticals there are less regulated parts of the market where charlatans thrive.

Comment: Not surprisingly... https://science.thewire.in/the-sciences/patanjali-ayurved-coronil-efficacy-claims-debunk-scientific-paper-phytomedicine/

Comment: @BryanKrause The comment you posted is timely for me. I learned just a couple hours ago that one of the doctors I've been seeing actually got her degree from a university that is considered to engage in "quackery". I started to question what she was telling me, and I thoroughly researched all of her education. It makes me seriously question not only her recommendations, but also that of *all* the doctors in the practice. One of the biggest challenges I find is determining if a doctor (or any practitioner) is a quack or ahead of the curve.

Comment: I still haven't found any type of medicine that combines accurate science & integrity.  Money, ego, power, religion, and hidden agendas seem to play a big role in so much of medicine.  When I do find a small pocket of quality science, it often is completely closed to anything that they can't prove. Finding honest practitioners with integrity who actually understand and value real science while still being open-minded feels nearly impossible at times.  ***We know so little and so much, and we need to embrace both simultaneously.***

Comment: If anyone is interested in chatting about the comments I just posted, please just post a comment to link to a chat room so we can talk about our experiences (and @ me here so I get notified).  I don't want to get too off-topic here!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket "`I still haven't found any type of medicine that combines accurate science & integrity.`" -- that's a ridiculous statement. And I gather that you didn't bother reading the link I posted above, which brings this whole question into doubt. Comments are for clarifying questions, not for rants about doctors and Big Pharma.